# PHP: Code won't work without oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle

I have some code with a variable holding a connection to a server:

```
$conn = oci_connect();
```

I have looked all over the script, and no other function uses the $conn variable (trust me on this). However, when I take it out, the script keeps on running forever. Why is this?

Although this specific $conn is not used, I have other functions used in the script that make connections the same way, using oci_connect(). I would say there may be over a hundred calls to oci_connect() through these other functions (which create their own $conn = oci_connect()). Could declaring the $conn = oci_connect() in my script have saved me some performance time, allowing the functions calling oci_connect() to use the already defined variable instead?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good idea to reuse the connection for your database operations within the same script. Why wouldn't you? After all, you are connecting to the same database with the same credentials....aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle connections may take longer than other DBMS equivalents but it doesn't take "forever". Additionally, the manual [clearly says](http://php.net/oci_connect) that:

> The second and subsequent calls to oci_connect() with the same
>   parameters will return the connection handle returned from the first
>   call. This means that transactions in one handle are also in the other
>   handles, because they use the same underlying database connection.

Assuming that such line is a performance trick is pretty adventurous IMHO. You've just inherited some spaghetti code that, as most spaghetti code out there, works by pure chance.